# Value in SwiftUI not being passed

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to pass that a values to let my item know what group it should be added to in Core Data.

Here are some pictures of my App.

Please note that itemsInGroup fetches all of the items that should be in the group.

After adding breakpoints in my app, the value of the group where the Item entity is being add is equal to nil.  This should have a value (which is set when the add item button is pressed).
Thank you for your help in advance.
**Main part of the code**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
        case first, second
        
        var id: Int {
            hashValue
        }
    }

@FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Group.timestamp, ascending: true)],
    animation: .default)
private var items: FetchedResults<Group>

@State var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
@State private var selectedGroup: Group? = nil

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { group in
                //                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                Text(group.title ?? "New group")
                ForEach(group.itemsInGroup) { item in
                    Text(item.title ?? "New Item")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    selectedGroup = group
                    activeSheet = .second
                }, label: {
                    Text("Add Item")
                })
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        }
        .toolbar {
            Button(action: {
                activeSheet = .first
            }) {
                Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
        switch(item) {
        case .first: AddGroupName()
        case .second: AddItemView(group: selectedGroup)
        }
    }
}

private func addItem() {
    withAnimation {
        let newItem = Group(context: viewContext)
        newItem.timestamp = Date()
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
    withAnimation {
        offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

**Where I add a new item**

```
struct AddItemView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

let group: Group?
@State var title = ""
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Form {
            TextField("Title", text: $title)
            Button(action: {
                let item = Item(context: viewContext)
                item.group = group
                item.title = title
                try? viewContext.save()
            }, label: {
                Text("Save")
            })
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Where I add a new group**

```
struct AddGroupName: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@State var title = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Form {
            TextField("Title", text: $title)
            Button(action: {
                let item = Group(context: viewContext)
                item.title = title
                item.timestamp = Date()
                try? viewContext.save()
            }, label: {
                Text("Save")
            })
        }
        
    }
}
}
```

My Core Data Model
[image]
[image]

Why is the group value not being passed and saved correctly?  It should be saved in the selectedGroup variable in the main part of the code.

When I try and add an item and save it to the core data database I get this error "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'group' between objects in different contexts"

Please note that I have tried setting selectedGroup equal to a value other than nil, but then this initial value is used when trying to add an item.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your `group` property using the @Binding property wrapper in `AddItemView`

```
 @Binding var group: Group
```

This way the @State property `selectedGroup` will be updated when the `AddItemView` is dismissed

Comment: @NightWing, any feedback on this?